# class outlets not able to understand

Tags: iphone

i am streching my hairs in understanding customcell implemention from [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMcgf.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMcgf.png): http://b00gizm.posterous.com/customizing-table-view-cells-for-fancy-user-i  tutorial.
i am also attaching the part where i am stuffing[image]

what is this textfieldcell.h doing here in classoutlets.
Please guide!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TextFieldCell`-class is there because you're making a custom UITableViewCell.
The outlet is to inform the custom textfield that this is the header-file that belongs to the cell.

If you read a little further down in the guide, this is what TextFieldCell.h should contain:

```
#import 


@interface TextFieldCell : UITableViewCell {  IBOutlet UITextField *textField; }

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

@end
```

Good luck ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!i understand that but not able to see TextFieldCell.h in class outlets in IB.Why if i have followed all the instructions.Even i can post my code in new thread.